# Partitioning single series into two geometric series to prove convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, geometric-series

I was asked to determine whether $\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{2}{9} + \frac{1}{27} + \frac{2}{81} + \frac{1}{243} + \frac{2}{729} +...$ converges or diverges and, should it converge, to show what it converges to. To do this, I took the approach of partitioning the series into the sum of two geometric sequences. Since I am very new to infinite series (started learning this today), I was wondering if my approach is correct.

$\alpha )$ Let $a_n = \frac{1}{3^{2n-1}}= \{\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{27}, \frac{1}{243},... \}$ and $b_n = \frac{2}{3^{2n}} = \{\frac{2}{9}, \frac{2}{81}, \frac{2}{729}, ... \}$. Then, due to the commutative property of addition,

$$\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{2}{9} + \frac{1}{27} + \frac{2}{81} + \frac{1}{243} + \frac{2}{729} +... = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$

$\beta)$ Notice that $a_n= \frac{1}{3^{2n-1}}=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{9})^{n-1}$ and $b_n=\frac{2}{3^{2n}} = \frac{2}{9}(\frac{1}{9})^{n-1}$.

$\gamma)$ Then,

$$\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{2}{9} + \frac{1}{27} + \frac{2}{81} + \frac{1}{243} + \frac{2}{729} +... \overset{\text{due to }\alpha, \beta}{=} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{9})^{n-1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{2}{9}(\frac{1}{9})^{n-1}$$

$$\overset{\text{due to g.s.}}{=} \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{9}} + \frac{\frac{2}{9}}{1-\frac{1}{9}} = \frac{5}{8}$$

where $\text{g.s.}$ is the following theorem regarding geometric series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a r^{n-1}=\frac{a}{1-r}$ for $r \in (-1, 1)$.

Is this solution correct? Thank you.

Comment: If you are just learning, better not apply any commutative property of addition to a series (which are not sums). Take a partial sum of the series and apply the commutative property to that (finite) sum. For series of non-negative terms it is true that we have commutativity for series, but you judge if that is a result that you have as proven at this point. Take also into account that for series with not definite sign commutativity is not true in general

Comment: You could say that every term is $\le \frac 2{3^n}$ and then compare to the geometric series...  Once you prove it is absolutely convergent, then you can rearrange terms as you've done

Comment: $\frac58$ is correct.   An alternative is $(\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{81} + \frac{1}{243} + \frac{1}{729} +\cdots)+ (\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{81}+ \frac{1}{729} +\cdots)$ $= \frac 12 +\frac 18$

Comment: Thank you all for your insightful comments!